# How to save .txt file contents separately for every open bracket to closed bracket in Python?

Tags: python

my current .txt file look like this:

```
[
"8.782897907000063,1.718493196000054",
"8.782768250000061,1.718278646000044",
"8.78276825100005,1.718376662000026"
]
[
"8.78288150700007,1.718478835000042",
"8.782897907000063,1.718493196000054"
]
[
"8.78288150700007,1.718478835000042",
"8.782897907000063,1.718493196000054",
"8.782897907000063,1.718493196000054",
"8.78288150700007,1.718478835000042",
"8.782897907000063,1.718493196000054"
]
[...... (4,000 more...)
```

I want to save every enclosed bracket into a separate single file and the new file will look like this:

```
[
"8.782897907000063,1.718493196000054",
"8.782768250000061,1.718278646000044",
"8.78276825100005,1.718376662000026"
]
```

And the next file will look like this:

```
[
"8.78288150700007,1.718478835000042",
"8.782897907000063,1.718493196000054"
]
```

and so on...

I know I how to save file for every line like this:

```
infile = 'file_name.txt'

with open(infile, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

counter = 1

for line in lines:

if line

outfile = 'file_name' + str(counter) + '.txt'

with open(outfile, 'w') as g:
    g.write(line)

counter += 1
```

But not sure about the above issue. Do you know how to do it in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what’s less clear is how this ought to be indented. Don’t make us guess; please [edit] to fix this. (On the desktop version of this site, paste your program, select it, and type ctrl-K to properly format it as code.)

Comment: Rather than deleting your previous question and trying again, the correct approach is to update your previous question. Did you try the code from the answer you received there? Why not? Or why didn't it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nee to append the content you read to a global variable, and when you end a block, write it to a new file, and start again

```py
infile = 'file_name.txt'

with open(infile, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

counter = 1
one_content = ""

for line in lines:
    one_content += line

    if line.startswith("]"): # ends block
        with open(f'file_name{counter}.txt', 'w') as g:
            g.write(one_content)
        counter += 1
        one_content = "" # reset
```